# get userAuthentication object from spring security context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

i have debug `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` there is a userAuthentication Object and that have my custom details as well.there's no getter to access this.how to get those details.

how to get token enhanced additional details from ?`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

Answer (score -1):

```
OAuth2Authentication principal =  (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Object object=principal.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
```